# В чем разница между LINQ to SQL и Entity Framework и когда, что лучше использовать?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

В чем разница между LINQ to SQL и Entity Framework и когда, что лучше использовать?

Comment: Что знаете - то и используйте. Для крупных проектов - только EF.

Comment: Только тот вопрос тоже отвечен слабо. Проще сказать, что linqtosql заброшен, а ef - развивается.